# How to force use a certain localization on field in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization

I'm using current phone localization, but is there a way to get certain localization on field?

> String get symptom => Intl.message('Symptom', name: 'symptom');

For example I need English **String** value for field `localizations.symptom` for statistics, but current locale is Japan.

There is a Text widget in Flutter with custom locale inside, mb exist something similar with  returning just String value? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some research, I get the desired solution:

```
context.localizations.symptom;                              // String in device localization
Intl.withLocale('en', () => context.localizations.symptom); // String in english localization
```